# Matrix $A$ is similar to diagonal matrix $D$. Determine the diagonal elements of $D$.

Tags: matrices, diagonalization

Matrix $A =\begin{bmatrix}5/2&3/2\\-5/2&13/2\end{bmatrix}$ and $D = \begin{bmatrix}u&0\\0&v\end{bmatrix}$

I know that $D = P^{-1}AP$.

Knowing that $P^{-1}P=I$,

$D = P^{-1}AP$

$D = A$

I tried answering $u = 5/2$ and $v = 13/2$ but it was wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Right answers below but first you can see that D=A is clearly wrong. D is visibly not equal to A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$AP = PD$

$P$ has column vectors $p_1,p_2$
and $PD = [p_1u, p_2 v]$

and $AP = [Ap_1,Ap_2]$

$Ap_1 = up_1$ and
$Ap_2 = vp_1$ if this is true then

$Ap_1  - up_1 = 0\\
Ap_1  - u Ip_1 = 0\\
(A-u I)p_1 = 0$

and 
$(A- u I)$ is a singular matrix.

and if $(A-u I)$ is singular then $\det (A-u I) = 0$

and similarly $\det(A-v I) = 0$

Comment: $det(\begin{bmatrix}5/2&3/2\\-5/2&13/2\end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix}u&0\\0&u\end{bmatrix} = (u-5)(u-4)$ and so $(v-5)(v-4)$. Is that correct? And which eigenvalues of $-5$ and $-4$ go with $u$ and $v$?

Comment: pick one for $u,$ pick the other for $v$ it doesn't matter which way you go.  by they way the eigenvalues are (5,4) not (-5,-4)

Answer (score 1):

$D = P^{-1}AP$ doesn't imply that $D=A$. The matrix multiplication isn't commutative.

As you know that $A$ is diagonalizable, you just need to find the eigenvalues of $A$ and these would be the entries $u,v$ in $D$. It's not hard to do that. In fact it boils down to solving the characteristic polynomial of $A$ and $\Delta_A = x^2 - 9x + 20$

Comment: I got $(3/5, 1)^T$ and $(1, 1)^T$. How do I know which one is $u$ and which one is $v$ and shouldn't they be one number instead of two?

Comment: @plumbus I'm not sure, but it seems you found eigenvectors. You need eigenvalues and they are -4 and -5. Any combination of them works as u and v

Comment: Ah ok. I read in your comment that I have to find the eigenvectors of A, so that's why I calculated the eigenvectors. And any combination of them works? Thanks.

Comment: @plumbus Oh, sorry for my mistake. Yeah lndeed both combinations u=-4; v=-5 and u=-5; v=-4 work